# Regular Expression Not Validating Correctly

Tags: regex, validation

I'm using the following: (`/^[A-Za-z0-9 '-\/]{3,20}$/`) to validate an address.

Something like "27a/67 Mount View Rd" is permitted,
but when entered as "Unit 27a/67 Mount View Rd" OR "27a / 67 Mount View Rd" it returns false.

The regular expression allows for spaces, so why is it refusing to validate the latter addresses?

You can test it out here: http://www.melbournemeditationcentre.com/meditation-courses/course-registration/

Comment: You have more than 20 characters in your "invalid" strings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
27a/67 Mount View Rd
27a / 67 Mount View Rd
Unit 27a/67 Mount View Rd
    ^    ^    ^    ^
    5   10   15   20
```

You have more than 20 characters in your invalid strings...